# How to predict filename when downloading a tarball from github by SHA?

Tags: github

How do I predict the download filename when downloading a project tarball from github by SHA?

#### For instance, when I download:

https://github.com/nette/nette/tarball/e9719f05fc9bbe1742c68ab7ddee640c99a3ec64

#### the filename (set by Content-Disposition) is:

nette-nette-v2.0.0-279-ge9719f0.tar.gz

#### The format appears to be:

{user}-{repo}-{most immediate predecssing tag}-{number of commits between SHA and tag}-g{SHA}.tar.gz

I want to predict the filename without having to know the "most immediate predecssing tag" or "number of commits between SHA and tag" and without renaming the downloaded file.

### edit:

I am really looking for a way to predict the filename without having to attempt to download the file. (Thanks to @Keith for pointing out that I did not specify this originally.)

Comment: How are you downloading the file? You can simply save the downloaded data in memory, and only make the file once you know the filename.

Comment: @nightcracker I want to download using something along the lines of: wget --content-disposition https://github.com/nette/nette/tarball/e9719f05fc9bbe1742c68ab7ddee640c99a3ec64

Answer (score 1):

The link redirects to the actual file name:

```
$ curl https://github.com/nette/nette/tarball/e9719f05fc9bbe1742c68ab7ddee640c99a3ec64 ; echo ""
<html><body>You are being <a href="https://nodeload.github.com/nette/nette/tarball/e9719f05fc9bbe1742c68ab7ddee640c99a3ec64">redirected</a>.</body></html>
$
```

You can capture the output of the `curl` command and extract the target URL. You can then do an ordinary `wget` on that URL.